# Retransmission in less than one second

Tags: tcp, arp

On my Linux machine I use `nc` to communicate with a echo server running on my android device. I use `nc` to send text to port 65303 of the android device. After entering test1 the same text is sent back from the mirror server. This is  why you always see the same text twice.

```
nc 192.168.1.24 -p 65303
test1
test1
test2
test2
```

Here my devices in more detail:

```
Mx Linux MX-19.4_x64 patito feo May 31 2020, Kernel: 4.19.0-20-amd64 x86_64
Samsung Galaxy A8 (2018) SM-A530F, Kernel: 4.4.111-22928167
Android App "Echo Server" from Shufai Studio
```

The android-device is connected over WiFi with my WiFi router, but my Linux machine has only an Ethernet-link to the same WiFi router. WiFi is turned off in my Linux machine. Both devices are in the same C-network 192.168.1.0/24.
Then I turn off the WiFi of the WiFi router, enter test3 and observe with `WireShark` the communication of the eth0-network-device of my Linux machine. After about 60s I turn on WiFi again.
I can see that **6** TCP-retransmissions take place with these times after the previous TCP-segment:

```
0.437 s
0.416 s
0.832 s
1.664 s
3.392 s
106.496 s
```

There are 3 things which  surprises me:

1. The first three transmission take place in less than one second. This is not according to RFC 6298, which says in chapter 2.4:

   > Whenever RTO is computed, if it is less than 1 second, then the RTO SHOULD be rounded up to 1 second.
2. The times should double for every retransmission, which is not the case for the 2nd retransmission. This is not according to RFC 6298, which states in chapter 5.5:

   > The host MUST set RTO <- RTO * 2 ("back off the timer").
3. It seems that the 6th retransmission was delayed and sent after I turned on WiFi again. Somehow my Linux machine was waiting for the connection to be available again. But I don't know how this is done! The *eth0*-network-device always is on and does not know that WiFi link between WiFi router and Android device was turned off for 60s.

After looking again in `WireShark` I can see that my Linux device is sending ARP requests asking for the MAC address of the Android device.

```
Address Resolution Protocol (request)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (1)
    Protocol type: IPv4 (0x0800)
    Hardware size: 6
    Protocol size: 4
    Opcode: request (1)
    Sender MAC address: HewlettP_2d:65:2c (e4:11:5b:2d:65:2c)
    Sender IP address: 192.168.1.242
    Target MAC address: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00)
    Target IP address: 192.168.1.24
```

This seems to be a way for the Linux machine to find out whether Android-device can be reached over the network. Once the target address is not `00:00:00_00:00:00` any more the android device is online again. Is the behaviour somewhere documented? Does anyone know more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP drivers do not obey blindly RFC 6298, which dates after all from
2011, from before networks achieved their current much faster speed.
Very many scientific papers were written about improving the algorithm
for high-speed networks, but I'm unable to say which one is followed
by your driver.

However, all current operating system contain tweaked and optimized
algorithms, where their parameters can often be modified further by
the machine administrator.

For example, in Windows there exists the registry parameter of
[TcpTimedWaitDelay](https://admx.help/?Category=SecurityBaseline&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.MSS::Pol_MSS_TcpMaxDataRetransmissions)
defined as:

> How many times unacknowledged data is retransmitted (**3 recommended**, 5 is default)

A similar behavior is what you are seeing:

- Two transmissions went through, the second one taking 0.416 s
- Three retransmissions were attempted, doubled each time :
  0.832 s, 1.664 s, 3.392 s
- After these three failed transmissions, the TCP driver abandoned this
  algorithm and passed to another method, this time involving ARP.

There is nothing shocking about it. I would be more shocked if no
improvements were attempted for this algorithm over the last 11 years
since 2011.